# Built custom control when the app was 32 bit, now that I am moving to 64 bit only the custom control cannot be placed

Tags: c#, reference, user-controls

Developed in 32. Am moving to 64 bit only because of driver issues of some supporting hardware. I can no longer run as 32 bit. I'm not gonna lie, I've had some issues.

I finally just created a new 64 bit app and copied all my source files and added them to the working 64 bit app. Everything is wourking except a user control is not showing up in the designer. When I try to add another user control I get the error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

[image]

It is clear that the user control is causing VS to look for the old 32 bit reference.

I have looked in the .cs, .resx files and I see nothing that would cause this to look for the wrong reference. The custom control is a control in this project, not a control from another project.

Is there somewhere in the hidden files that control a project and user controls that might have an old dll referenced? I used to have a compiled stand along user control with the same name in the toolbox. I abandon doing it that way a few years ago on this project.

**EDIT** The Flir.Atlas.Image version 2.xxxxxxx is the 32 bit version. IT is not referenced in the project. The 64 bit version 6.0.18050.1001 IS referenced in the project. It seems the user control built in the originally with the 32 bit.

Comment: Well, what is ```Flir.Atlas.Image``` does the reference exist in the solution? is it copied to the build?

Comment: Yes. Flir.Atlas.Image (x64 version) is referenced in the solution.

Comment: Is it copied to the build folder? is it something you compiled or is it a third party .dll ?

Comment: It's third party. A lot of other functions depend on it in the dll - it is there an working properly. The dll and everything else in the x64 folder gets copied by a dos bat file after compiling. The dll is definitely in the build.

Comment: Just to be clear the issue is the custom control is looking for the 32 bit not 64 bit dll.